# Include nested json in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested

I added an object nested in another object using the model. Just like this:

Ingresso model ->

```
def as_json(options=nil)
  super(:include => [:usuario, :tipo_de_ingresso])
end
```

In `tipo_de_ingresso` model, I want to add another object nested. here:

```
def as_json(options=nil)
  super(:include => :entradas)
end
```

But when I get the the `ingressos.json`, I lost `entradas`. If I get `tipo_de_ingressos.json`, `entradas` are nested, ok, but when I get `ingressos.json`, they are not there.

How can I get `entradas` nested in `tipo_de_ingresso` when I call `ingresso`?

Comment: PS: You might find the [RABL Gem](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) helpful if you need to do more complex json operations. That way you can define actual views for your json responses instead of bundling it up in the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
# /app/models/Ingresso.rb

def as_json(options=nil)
  super(:include => [:usuario => {}, :tipo_de_ingresso => { :include => :entradas }])
end
```

**EDIT:**

changed `[:usuario, ...` to `[:usuario => {}, ...`

Comment: It works! I knew that was something like this, but I'm not very familiar with Rails. Thanks again :-)